# How can I resolve "Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86-mingw32"] but your local platforms are ["ruby", "x86_64-linux"]"

Tags: ruby, bundler, travis-ci, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I'm building a rails site on a Windows machine but when I check in my Gemfile.lock I get the following error on my Travis builds:

```
Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86-mingw32"] but your local platforms are ["ruby", "x86_64-linux"], and there's no compatible match between those two
```

lists

Here is the full log: https://travis-ci.org/bikebike/BikeBike/builds/222395810#L654

I looked at my Gemfile.lock and it states:

```
PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32
```

Which appears to be part of the issue. I've tried putting any windows specific gems in a `platforms` block:

```
platforms 'mswin', 'mingw', 'mswin64', 'x64_mingw' do
  gem 'tzinfo-data'

  group :test do
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0'
    gem 'win32console', require: false
  end
end
```

But the Gemfile.lock looks the same.

Here is my full [Gemfile](https://github.com/bikebike/BikeBike/blob/development/Gemfile) and [Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/bikebike/BikeBike/blob/development/Gemfile.lock).

I can temporarily get around the issue by removing the Gemfile.lock file from git but this is not best practice. Is there anyway that I can commit my Gemfile.lock file and continue to develop on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 62):

Run the following two commands on the command line:

```
bundle lock --add-platform ruby
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

This will add the two platforms in Gemfile.lock

I had the same error when deploying to google cloud. But after running these two commands ruby and x86_64-linux were added and the issue was resolved.

Comment: this worked for me. i accidentally deleted the linux line after migrating away from PopOS, which broke my AWS deployment, and the 2nd command here fixed it

Answer (score 8):

For Ruby 2.5.1 I solved this on my VPS by adding also the platforms mentioned in the error message to the platform list section of the `gemfile.lock`:

```
PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32
  ruby 
  x86_64-linux
```

Only then, running following commands from app's directory (as already shown in [taz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44350326/2648551))

```
bundle lock --add-platform ruby
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

lead to success.

Comment: The answer you referred did NOT work for me so I posted exactly what made my app work. It was also required that I edited the platform list @colidyre

Comment: This worked and I didn't need to run the two commands you mentioned.