# Cannot add platform to Gemfile.lock using bundle lock

Tags: heroku, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I am trying to push a project to Heroku for the first time using `git push heroku master`. However, I end up getting the following error:

> Your bundle only supports platforms ["arm64-darwin-21"] but your local platform
> is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.

Running `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` in turn results in the following output:

> [17052, #<Thread:0x000000015307bc60 run>, #<NameError: uninitialized constant Gem::Source

... followed by a hundred lines of different paths on my computer.

Does anyone know how to interpret and solve this kind of output?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 20):

Are you using M1 Mac? if yes then which means the platform is arm64-darwin-20, but the production environment is not.

Try to run below two commands and that will add the two platforms in Gemfile.lock

```
bundle lock --add-platform ruby
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

`rm -rf Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install`

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I am using M1 Mac. By running `bundle lock --add-platform ruby` I still get a similarly looking output: [18529, #<Thread:0x000000013a07bc60 run>, #<NameError: uninitialized constant Gem::Source

Comment: Please try to remove your Gemfile.lock file with below command rm -rf Gemfile.lock and rerun bundle install

Comment: Followed your suggested steps but the problem still remains. Errors are the same as before.

Comment: It didn't work for me to remove the Gemfile.lock (that actually UNDOES the platform additions). It worked otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

It's solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429685/how-can-i-resolve-your-bundle-only-supports-platforms-x86-mingw32-but-your) too. FYI

- bundle lock --add-platform ruby
- bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux

Comment: This is the right answer I think

Answer (score 1):

The first answer in the following stack overflow thread did the job for me:

[Rails uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130295/rails-uninitialized-constant-bundler-nameerror)

```
#remove project-specific settings
rm -rf .bundle/

# remove project-specific cached gems and repos
rm -rf vendor/cache/

# remove the saved resolve of the Gemfile
rm -rf Gemfile.lock

# rebundle 
bundle install
```